# Issues with JQuery prev() method

Tags: jquery

I want to use JQuery's prev() method to select the previous li item from the one I give the `current` class to and remove the border of it. However it's not working. Here is the [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/Douglas_Symb/9wmybyqm/).

My code:

**HTML**

```
  <nav id="nav">
    <ul id="navlist">
      <a href="about.php"><li class="navitem">About</li></a>
      <a href="portfolio.php"><li class="navitem">Portfolio</li></a>
      <a href="blog.php"><li class="navitem">Blog</li></a>
      <a href="contact.php"><li class="navitem current">Contact</li></a>
    </ul>
  </nav>
```

**CSS**

```
#navlist {
  position: relative;
  top: 12px;
}
#navlist a {
  color: #190912;
}
.navitem {
  display: block;
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.25rem;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #440b2e;
}
.current {
  border: 4px solid #440b2e;
  background-color: #966b9d;
  color: #f2f2ed;
}
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
$(function() {
  $("li.current").prev().css("border", "none");
});
```

I am using JQuery 1.11.X. Thank you.

Comment: invalid markup.........!!!!

Comment: `.prev()` looks at previous element, prev element in this case is not `<li class="navitem">`

Comment: Thank you everyone for catching my oops on the markup, huge help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to put a valid markup like this:

```js
$(function() {
  $("li.current").prev().css("border", "none");
});
```

```css
#navlist {
  position: relative;
  top: 12px;
}
#navlist a {
  color: #190912;
}
.navitem {
  display: block;
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.25rem;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #440b2e;
}
.current {
  border: 4px solid #440b2e;
  background-color: #966b9d;
  color: #f2f2ed;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav id="nav">
  <ul id="navlist">
    <li class="navitem"><a href="about.php">About</a></li>
    <li class="navitem"><a href="portfolio.php">Portfolio</a></li>
    <li class="navitem"><a href="blog.php">Blog</a></li>
    <li class="navitem current"><a href="contact.php">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

and js seems to be valid and will work as `li` has a previous siblings item now.

Comment: As a side note, to make all the space filled by LIs clickable, not just the anchor, you could add as CSS rule: `#navlist a {
    display: block;
}`

Answer (score 2):

Your HTML is invalid. Only `li` elements can be direct descendants of a `ul` so the `a` should be inside the `li`. Once you fix this your code should work fine.

```
<nav id="nav">
    <ul id="navlist">
        <li class="navitem"><a href="about.php">About</a></li>
        <li class="navitem"><a href="portfolio.php">Portfolio</a></li>
        <li class="navitem"><a href="blog.php">Blog</a></li>
        <li class="navitem current"><a href="contact.php">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

[**Updated fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/9wmybyqm/4/)

Comment: Thank you you were correct about my markup being incorrect. However with the Jquery I used the prev() method because I have a border-bottom property on the previous li, not a top border on the `current` li.

Comment: Ah, in which case the use of `prev()` is fine. I have updated my answer for you.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is your HTML is malformed. ul tags are only allowed to have li inside them. You have `<a>` tags inside the ul.

Comment: this is not answer put it in comment